# Turn-Off logging of sensitive query statements to SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to leverage Snowflake's ENCRYPT(,,) and ENCRYPT_RAW(,,) function and I wanted to avoid logging the query statements to SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY which is visible to SYSADMINS and stored inside Snowflake. The ENCRYPT() function contains password.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs for `ENCRYPT`:

> The function’s parameters are masked for security. Sensitive information such as the following is not visible in the query log and is not visible to Snowflake:
>
> - The string or binary value to encrypt or decrypt.
> - The passphrase or key.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/encrypt.html

So this shouldn't be a problem for the question around `ENCRYPT(,,)` and `ENCRYPT_RAW(,,)`.