# Where to Store Secrets to be used in Snowpark

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake/Snowpark if I need a credential of any kind during runtime of a Snowpark script, is there any built-in functionality to store secrets or sensitive information in Snowflake? If not, where would one store such information to not be shown in Query History and so on?

I see there is a "Secrets" section in Snowflake, but it appears this is only used for a ServiceNow connector.

Comment: Looks like Secrets functionality will be expanding with External Network Access for Snowpark. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXnjvyeb-Q8

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ENCRYPT()`/`DECRYPT()` in queries to avoid Snowflake logging the sensitive values.

> The function’s parameters are masked for security. Sensitive information such as the following is not visible in the query log and is not visible to Snowflake:
>
> - The string or binary value to encrypt or decrypt.
> - The passphrase or key.

Then you can use those values when calling your Snowflake functions.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/encrypt
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66502518/132438